# Replace characters in a list by column rather than by row

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I have the following lists:

```
counter = [13]
instruments = ['3\t     ---', '2\t    /   \\', '1\t   /     \\', '0\t---       \\       ---', '-1\t           \\     /', '-2\t            \\   /', '-3\t             ---']
score = ['|*************|']
```

What I am trying to do is to replace the characters in the instruments list with the characters from the score list (excluding the `|`).

I am currently experiencing the following issues

The characters are being replaced row by row, rather than column by column.

Instrument List:

```
3        ---
2       /   \
1      /     \
0   ---       \       ---
-1             \     /
-2              \   /
-3               ---
```

Score List:

```
|*************|
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
3        ***
2       *   *
1      *     *
0   ***       *       
-1             *     
-2              *   
-3
```

Current Output:

```
3        ***
2       *   *
1      *     *
0   ***       *       **
-1                  
-2                 
-3
```

This is how I am currently replacing the characters in the `instruments` list:

```
for elements in counter:
    current_counter = elements
    count = 0
    for elements in instrument_wave:
        amplitude, form = elements.split('\t')
        for characters in form:
            if characters in ['-', '/', '\\']:
                form = form.replace(characters, '*', 1)
                count += 1
            if count == current_counter:
                break
        for characters in form:
            if characters in ['-', '/', '\\']:
                form = form.replace(characters, '')
        if '-' not in amplitude:
            amplitude = ' ' + amplitude
        new_wave = amplitude + "\t" + form
        waveform.append(new_wave)
```

Any help would be appreciated, especially with regards to how I should fix my replace character to make it go column by column rather than row by row.

Comment: For the first part, probably easiest to just swap your axis with a nested for loop, do your stuff, and swap it back.

Comment: Can you supply a better example of what input/output you are expecting? It's unclear from the above.

Comment: I have made some changes to the examples provided. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Nathan could you please advice as to how I would swap my axis?

Comment: It's still unclear how you expect `score` to generate your result. The 2nd example seems to be unrelated to the original problem and makes the problem even more complex. It's very likely the second part should be a whole different question, as it is (solution wise) unrelated.

Comment: @TemporalWolf the score files are simply generated by reading a file from directory. There are over 30 files with different 'scores', and it is a similar case for instruments. I am updating the code to show the segment of how the list is being generated.

Comment: I have also removed the 'second' issue from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your first issue, you need to iterate via columns.

If you zip the lists (via [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), as they are not all the same length), you can then go through them in order and truncate the result:

```
import itertools

cols = list(itertools.zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=" "))
for i in range(3, 17):  # skip negative signs
    cols[i] = "".join(cols[i]).replace('-', '*', 1)
    cols[i] = "".join(cols[i]).replace('/', '*', 1)
    cols[i] = "".join(cols[i]).replace('\\', '*', 1)
fixed = map("".join, zip(*cols[:17]))  # no need to zip longest

for l in fixed:
    print(l)
```

See a working example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PrimeWatchfulFreesoftware), which outputs:

```
3        ***     
2       *   *    
1      *     *   
0   ***       *  
-1             * 
-2              *
-3
```

Note it does pad the lists out with spaces, so you may want to `.strip()` the results if it isn't just for printing. Adapting that to your score input I'll leave up to you.

Another option, which is probably clearer:

```
def convert_and_truncate(lst, cutoff):
    result = []
    for str in lst:
        str = str[0] + str[1:].replace('-', '*')  # skip the negative signs
        str = str.replace('/', '*')
        str = str.replace('\\', '*')
        result.append(str[:cutoff])  # truncate
    return result
```

Because we're truncating the rest of the list, it doesn't matter that replace is changing them all.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this without using `intertools`. I do not have any experience with it whatsoever.

Comment: [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) is only being used to extend the builtin `zip()` functionality. It works just like zip, except it pads the short columns with the `fillvalue` instead of truncating.

Comment: Thank you. I will play around with this and see how it works.

Comment: For some reason when I try to implement itertools it works BUT I get a `-` for the very first start. https://imgur.com/a/Bqn8W

Comment: you likely need to adjust the `range(3, 17)`. I hard coded values which will be dynamically changed via your score.

Comment: How do you limit the replacing to replace exactly n * only, depending on the amount of * in `score`?

Comment: @PatrickArtner by specifying the range of the replacement. I don't have the proper source data, so I've demonstrated it on a list of strings where 17 returns the proper value. The same value is used to truncate the final output.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it was the `3` that was throwing off the value.

Comment: You would somehow need to calculate in which colum the `n-th` star is - not quite sure how to do that for automating this... but without more data its difficult. I simply count them, thats easier to automate :) - neater then mine though, +1

Comment: @PatrickArtner `"*******---".rfind("*")` although if you can mix the characters, ala `"***---***"` a more complex solution is needed.

Comment: Is there a way to align the `white space` at the end of each row to the distance of the last `*` that was printed?

Comment: `lst = map(string.strip, lst)`, where `lst` in my example would be `fixed`. You do have to `import string` to be able to use it this way.

Comment: @TemporalWolf first replace all the `\t` with x amount of spaces. Then loop over your list where `new_list[i][j] = old_list[j][i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Without itertools, instead self padding to longest part in list:

```
counter = [16]
instruments = ['3\t     ---', '2\t    /   \\', '1\t   /     \\', '0\t---       \\       ---', '-1\t           \\     /', '-2\t            \\   /', '-3\t             ---']
score = ['|*************|']


# get longes part list
maxL = max ( len(p) for p in instruments)

#enlarge all to max length
instrum2 = [k + ' '* (maxL-len(k)) for k in instruments]

# mask out leading - to ~ (we reverse it later)
instrum3 = [k if k[0] != '-' else '~'+''.join(k[1:]) for k in instrum2]

# transpose and join to one lengthy sentence, #### are where we later split again
trans = '####'.join(map(''.join,zip(*instrum3)))


# replace the right amount of /-\ with * after that, replace with space instead   
cnt = 0
maxCnt = score[0].count('*')
result = []
for t in trans:
    if t in '/-\\':
        if cnt < maxCnt:
            result.append('*')
            cnt+=1
        else:
            result.append(' ')
    else:
        result.append(t)

# resultlist back to string and split into columns again
result2 = ''.join(result)
trans2 = result2.split('####')

# transpose back to rows and make - correct
trans3 = [''.join(k).replace('~','-') for k in zip(*trans2 )] 

for p in trans3:
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
3        ***             
2       *   *            
1      *     *           
0   ***       *          
-1             *        
-2              *       
-3
```

Comment: This prints an additional 8 characters that are not supposed to be there. This was my first solution as well, to the problem, but the output is not what is required.